# Can you ADD permission for external Users (not within a sub-site) to access specific items inside a specific list via Workflow?

Tags: workflow, list-view

Creating a high level sub-site for top management (imagine VP, CEO, etc.), whom has their own respective PA/assistants. These top management wanted to let their PA/assistants update items in the sub-site on behalf of them, while limiting the PA/assistants access to relevant items only.

Items mentioned here are say, agenda items, which has a column called "Delegation". Delegation is basically which top manager is responsible for each of these agenda items.

e.g. There's CEO, CTO and CMO in the sub-site, and there's 5 items in the agenda list, Agenda 1 is delegated to CEO, 2, 3 and 4 is delegated to CTO, and 5 is delegated to CMO.

Personal assistant to CEO need to be able to see and edit Agenda 1 ONLY, assistant to CTO needs to see and edit items 2, 3 and 4, so on and so forth.

Any idea how can I get this sorted? I tried creating a separate view called "CEO's Action Items", dropped it into a page (using web part), and shared that page with the personal assistant. Issue is that it seems like the personal assistant still can't see the agenda items (1, in this case) because she doesn't have permission to see the list items themselves, only the page.

Is my best bet a workflow that updates the permission every time an agenda item is edited?